# MySQL convert comma separated result into Individual Columns

Tags: mysql

Im not sure whether my questions is right or not. I've been searching for the same term but seems none is near the result, I've table as below image:[image: table img]
Whats the suitable ways to get the result of 'Interested_in' column in individual column for each values with the result of "yes" & "no", which is stored as comma separated values?

I've tried below query but no luck!

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(intereste_in,',',1) AS col1,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(intereste_in,',',2),',',-1) AS col2,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(intereste_in,',',3),',',-1) AS col3,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(intereste_in,',',4),',',-1) AS col4,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(intereste_in,',',5),',',-1) AS col5,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(intereste_in,',',6),',',-1) AS col6,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(intereste_in,',',7),',',-1) AS col7,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(intereste_in,',',8),',',-1) AS col8,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(intereste_in,',',9),',',-1) AS col9,
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(intereste_in,',',-1) AS col10
  FROM(SELECT unifying_column, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT interested_in LIMIT 10) AS intereste_in FROM tblName_test
  GROUP BY unifying_column) AS subtable;
```

Cheers

Comment: Are "yes" & "no" saved in the the column Interested_In? as I don't see them in the sample data you've shared?

Comment: @DoaaMagdy,nope. its stored as the value itself

Comment: So for example If you're displaying Interested_In for the first record the output you want is (Toys & games = Yes, Beauty = Yes, Watching TV / Movies / Cartoon = Yes, Shopping = Yes) ... This way there will not be any "No"s as you consider the value itself as a "Yes" ... am I right or there is something missing?

Comment: There will be NO, for which is NOT inserted in the table. Because this value come from a multiple checkboxes, which ever checked is inserted, which is a YES. Whichever not checked, will not be inserted, which is a NO =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So maybe something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.Inserted_In LIKE '%Shopping%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as Shooping,
       CASE WHEN t.Inserted_In LIKE '%Beauty%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as Beauty,
       CASE WHEN t.Inserted_In LIKE '%Toys%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as Toys,
       ...
FROM ...
```

Comment: Worked like charmed @Sagi. Though need to add "End" after the "ELSE" statement. =D

Comment: This solution means that you have to write down each value such as "Shopping, Beauty, ... " ... in the query?? ... What if any other values were added to "Interest_In" field by the users??!!

Comment: Then you have to manually insert them into them query. You have to create each column, if you want it dynamic, then it's a job for Dynamic SQL which is more complicated.